# Unit testing method that uses already tested method

Tags: unit-testing

Assume we have class `Handler` and class `Validator`. The `Handler` uses `Validator` to validate incoming requests.

The `Validator` class is unit tested, whether returns appropriate error etc.

Later, we want to create unit tests for `Handler`. The `Validator` has already unit tests, so how would the test for `Handler` look?

Will we write the same tests as for `Validator` whether `Handler` returns the appropriate error (retrieved from `Validator` class)? It doesn't make sense to me.

So how would the unit test for `Handler` class look in this case?

Comment: It is not clear what is the relationship between Handler and Validator? e.g. is Handler derived from Validator or something else? Please be more specific.

Comment: I added relationship between these classes in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't re-test the `Validator`'s logic in the `Handler`'s **unit** test.

The idea of **unit** (as opposed to component, integration, or end-to-end tests) is to isolate the logic of the minimal unit (usually a class) you're testing.

The textbook solution for this would be to mock the `Validator` and then test that the `Handler` properly reacts to different behaviors the `Validator` may have.

You didn't tag the question with any programming language, but any half-decent language should have some library to allow mocking. E.g., here's how I'd do it in [java](/questions/tagged/java) using [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito) and [junit](/questions/tagged/junit):

```java
// Imports snipped for brevity's sake
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class HandlerTest {
    // Create a mock Validator
    @Mock
    private Validator validator;

    private Handler handler;

    // Set up the handler being tested with said validator
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        handler = new Handler(validator);
    }

    @Test
    void handlePassedValidation() {
        // Mock the validator with a "passing" validation
        when(validator.isValid()).thenReturn(true);
      
        handler.handle();

        // Assert the handler did what it should when the validation passed
    }

    @Test
    void handleFailedValidation() {
        // Mock the validator with a "failing" validation
        when(validator.isValid()).thenReturn(false);
      
        handler.handle();

        // Assert the handler did what it should when the validation failed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The mocking solution that Mureinik presented in his answer is indeed the textbook solution. It is what most people on the planet do, and what most people consider normal. In my opinion, it is also deeply misguided, and I am not the only one who thinks this way:

- In the video *Thoughtworks - TW Hangouts: Is TDD dead?* ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9quxZsLcfo)) at 21':10'' **Kent Beck** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck)) says "My personal practice is I mock almost nothing."
- In the same video, at 23':56'' **Martin Fowler** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler_(software_engineer))) adds "I'm with Kent, I hardly ever use mocks."
- In the Fragile Test section of his book *xUnit Test Patterns: Refactoring Test Code* ([xunitpatterns.com](http://xunitpatterns.com/)) author **Gerard Meszaros** states "extensive use of Mock Objects causes overcoupled tests."
- In his presentation *TDD, where did it all go wrong?* ([InfoQ](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/tdd-original/), [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM)) at 49':32'' **Ian Cooper** says "I argue quite heavily against mocks because they are overspecified."

If you would like to read more about why mocks are a bad idea, see my blog post: [michael.gr - On Mock Objects and Mocking](https://blog.michael.gr/2023/01/mocking.html)

A better way to handle this is a method that I call ***Incremental Integration Testing***. This means never mock anything, always integrate the actual dependencies in your tests, (or fakes thereof, but never mocks,) and simply arrange the order in which your tests are executed so that the most dependent-upon classes are tested first, and classes that depend on them are tested afterwards. This way, the test for the `Handler` can make use of the `Validator` and take it for granted that it works,  because the test for the `Validator` has already run, and it has passed.

Unfortunately, testing frameworks offer very little, if any, support for executing tests in a particular order. I have written a tool that will take care of this for maven-based java projects, but you might not be using java, or maven, or you might not be willing to use some weird tool that some guy built. Luckily, there is a manual workaround: Testing frameworks tend to execute tests in alphabetic order, so you can still enforce the order of execution of your tests by naming them in such a way that their alphabetic order coincides with the order in which they should be executed. For example, you can name your tests `T01_ValidatorTest`, `T02_HandlerTest`, etc. so that the test for `Validator` always runs before the test for `Handler`. You might also have to similarly name your packages and/or namespaces.

For more information about Incremental Integration Testing see my blog: [michael.gr - Incremental Integration Testing](https://blog.michael.gr/2022/10/incremental-integration-testing.html)

Comment: That is a very informative answer. Thanks